# MySql is null vs is not null performance

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query where I am basically doing a left outer join and checking if the joined value is null

```
select count(T1.code) 
from ( select code 
       from asset 
       where type = 'meter' 
       and creation_time <= '2022-04-29 00:00:00' 
       and (deactivation_time > '2022-04-28 00:00:00' or deactivation_time is null ) 
       group by code
       ) as T1 
left join ( select asset_code 
            from amr_midnight_data 
            where server_time between '2022-04-28 00:00:00' and '2022-04-29 00:00:00' 
            group by asset_code
         ) as T2 on T1.code = T2.asset_code 
Where T2.asset_code is null;
```

This query takes 3 seconds to execute, but if I replace the is null at the end with is not null, it takes less then a second. Why is there a performance difference here and what alternatives do I have to make my original query faster?

Comment: Properly formatted SQL is so much easier to read, and to write.

Comment: How large are the data sets in the two cases?

Comment: Both asset table and amr_midnight_data has million rows.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the EXPLAIN.  A guess...  Changing to `IS NOT NULL` lets the Optimizer change `LEFT JOIN` to `JOIN`, which lets it start with `amr_midnight_data` which might optimize better.

I think that the `LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ... ) .. IS [NOT] NULL` can be replaced with

```
WHERE [NOT] EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM amr_midnight_data
              WHERE asset_code = T1.code
                AND server_time >= '2022-04-28'
                AND server_time  < '2022-04-28' + INTERVAL 1 DAY )
```

That would like to have `INDEX(asset_code, server_time)`

`EXISTS` is faster than `SELECT .. GROUP BY` because it can stop as soon as one matching row is found.

`asset` would probably benefit from `INDEX(type, creation_time)` or (to make it "covering"):

```
INDEX(time, creation_time, deactivation_time, code)
```

If you wish to discuss further, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables and `EXPLAIN` for each `SELECT`.

Comment: We have tested with not exists as well and it performs way slower then join is not null

Comment: please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE for both tables and EXPLAIN for each SELECT.